# Which series is this girl getting robbed and tied up from?

Tags: identification-request

I have seen this picture online quite a lot lately, and I have been wondering which series it comes from. I tried searching but did not find any results.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a original piece of art (pixiv) made by [柳田史太 (NSFW)](http://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=1774701&lang=zh) This piece of art is said to be based on 
[Tezuka Rin, from the katawa shoujo series](http://katawashoujo.wikia.com/wiki/Rin_Tezuka)

[image]

After a simple [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-the-source-of-an-anime-image-using-reverse-image-search) only came up with allot of 9gag/reddit and similar results. I decided to first identify the character, after some cropping. And a few failed search results I came to know that the character was based of [Tezuka Rin, from the katawa shoujo series](http://katawashoujo.wikia.com/wiki/Rin_Tezuka)

Shortly after with a bit help of comments given on both 9gag and reddit I managed to find out that it was a original piece of art made by [NSFW pixiv artist: 柳田史太](http://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=1774701&lang=zh) or as she is also known [Humitan](https://twitter.com/humitan)

The image is based on a simple word joke Hand-Tie(hentai). And also seems to be a word play, as *"rob"* and *"Tie a Knot"* is said to be pronounced in the same way. (can't confirm this as I don't speak the language)

I also seen some messages floating around that the image has been featured in manga order a few years back. But so far I have not been able to find it in there.

Comment: Tie is [結ぶ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/215409/m0u/%E7%B5%90%E3%81%B6/) musubu, and rob is [盗む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/169338/m0u/%E7%9B%97%E3%82%80/) nusumu.

Comment: That would make the *-te* forms *musunde* and *nusunde*, which sound even more alike.