# What anime is this blond hair girl wearing pink hair ribbons from?

Tags: merchandise

I want to cosplay as her. Thanks for answering.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Anime.SE. Could you add some more info, like where did you get/buy this keychain? Meanwhile, while waiting for the community to answer it, you could also try [searching anime character database](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/36843/2516), and if you got the answer, feel free to post a self-answer on the "answer" box below. Thanks!

Comment: As per https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/are-questions-regarding-cosplay-or-anime-related-items-still-on-topic, please provide information as to why you think it is from an anime.

Answer (score 6):

That would be [Beatrice](http://rezero.wikia.com/wiki/Beatrice) from the [Re:Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World) series
[image]