# How do I find an anime or manga only from characters names?

Tags: resources

The only thing I know is that it is a manga that has an anime, and I think the main character's name is Hana but I'm not sure if she’s the main character, and I think she also has a cat named Mero.

How do I find the anime/manga?

Comment: i would vote to close as duplicate because of [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/36843/1587) however while the link you can specify if they are a main character or not you can search by name from what i can tell or if they have any pets/mascots

Answer (score 1):

Just Google "anime" "hana" "mero" "cat", that's the best way to find it. It should come up with something. Anything else you can remember about it will help. Otherwise you won't be able to find it.